# How to flush the cache

Tags: google-apps-script

In Apps Script I need a way to flush the cache regardless of key. Alternatively I need a way to find all the keys which are currently cached.

When we cache items we create the key based on a number of dynamic properties so we can't be sure what keys are in the cache at any one time.

Is there a way to do either of the above in AppsScript? Do I need to write out my keys to a log somewhere and then when I want to flush it just do remove all on my saved list of keys?

I've looked at the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service but can't find anything so I'm not too hopeful.

Just wondered if anyone else has a solution for knowing what keys are in the cache?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a way to do it, but it looks like each item will expire after 6 hours, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#parameters_3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way to do it like that. A better way to invalidate the cache is to store a version inside each cached object and keep the version in scriptProperties too.
Whenever you read from the cache ignore it if its version is lower than your global version from scriptproperties.
To invalidate the cache(s) simply increment your version from scriptProperties.

Comment: That scriptProperty can be cached as well, only needing to read it shen the cache expires. Note that one of the cache put variants allows for 6 hours of cache too.

Comment: Is reading from the cache faster than reading from a property?

Answer (score -1):

Cache is faster than properties? Don't think so, check out this:

```
function propertiesUser() { // 1272.0 , 1135.0
  var value = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
  var key = 'ab';
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty(key, value);
  var i = 0;
  var t = Date.now();
  while (i<100) {
    Logger.log( PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty(key))
    i++
  }
  Logger.log( Date.now()-t);
}

function propertiesScript() { // 1190.0
  var value = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
  var key = 'ab';
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(key, value);
  var i = 0;
  var t = Date.now();
  while (i<100) {
    Logger.log( PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(key))
    i++
  }
  Logger.log( Date.now()-t);
}

function cache() { // 4141.0
  var value = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
  var key = 'ab';
  CacheService.getUserCache().put(key, JSON.stringify(value))
  var i = 0;
  var t = Date.now();
  while (i<100) {
    Logger.log( CacheService.getUserCache().get(key) )
    i++
  }
  Logger.log( Date.now()-t);
}
```

Comment: Here you test both writing and reading values with acquiring the reference to the storage. That's a bad test.