# What is the size of the cache provided by CacheService using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, caching

What is the maximum size of the CacheService ?

I know the maximum time something can be stored in cache is 21600 seconds, but I can't find how large the sizes of the publicCache and the privateCache actually are and how we can findout how much space (stll) is available in cache.

As the cache can't be flushed (see [How to flush the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398885/how-to-flush-the-cache)) and there seems to be no way retrieving all keys from the cache (in order to delete all objects from the cache), I think the kind of info I'm asking for is important.

Best would be (of course) to provide info about cachesize, keys and allow flushing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned the CacheService size is undocumented. There is a  100KB maximum amount of data stored per key but multiple keys are possible. In [an experiment 10MB worth of data was stored](https://plus.google.com/+FaustinoRodriguez/posts/61sFPFZ9ZPa) using multiple keys. This limit was hit due to execution timeout so more may be possible.

You may want to look at this community developed [CacheHandler library](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/database-abstraction-and-google-apps-script/database-caching/) if you are anticipating on using CacheService for a lot of temporary data storage.

Comment: Very helpful! 10 Mb is more then enough for me. I knew the site (looking at converting from VBA to GAS), but haven't seen the cachehandler. I HOPE Google will not reduce available cache at some point in time as it might break code if people start relying on the (at least0 10 Mb amount

Comment: good answer. dont rely on cache size, it will likely shrink/grow depending on external factors like other scripts using it up from a global pool for all users. At least thats how the appengine shared-cache works. In appengine you can purchase a dedicated cache, not in apps script.

Comment: @ZigMandel agree and good point to note that as overall cache size is undocumented it's at risk of being changed without notice

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to store large items https://github.com/yinonavraham/GoogleAppsScripts/tree/master/EnhancedCacheService

Answer (score 2):

the documentation does not say how large the cache is.
Even in appengine when using a non-dedicated cache, you dont know how much you will get.
you can do a lot with whats available. Use the expiration time, and use my answer to the question you linked ([How to flush the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398885/how-to-flush-the-cache)) for a way to "force-expire" individial cached elements. Seems that what you primarily want is to expire them all at once, and the linked answer says how to do it.

Comment: Indeed I want to do that (and I do use your method), but nevertheless it seems good to know about the size available as I might want to store more info in cache if I know in future I won't have problems. I use a combination of properties and cache. One thing I noticed is that properties and cache have things in common, but have methods with different functionality. Suggestion : provide similar functionality extending what is available now. This can't be very difficult nor timeconsuming.