# Google Scripts CacheService Optimizaiton/ Limit

Tags: json, caching, google-apps-script

I found the CacheService is quite fast (duh) so decided to create a CacheManager to store a whole manner of things.

JS Object --> JSON--> Blob --> Zip --> base64 encoded string

if the base64 string is > 1E5 chars (100kb) I create an MD5 checksum for the base64 string then split into 100kb sections and then cache those separately as a multipart zip string

I was able to store/ recall ~3MB of raw JSON data in this fashion in ~1.2s (similar speed to a DriveApp API call)

I tried searching for an overall limit for how many total cached objects could be created but didn't find much. Is anyone aware of of an overall limit or performance degradation with large numbers of cached strings?

[Source Code](http://pastebin.podrezo.com/p/59641c9b405a7b5504c0838a) for my "cache manager"

Edit: Fixed source URL

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented value for this in the docs, but you can try the tests conducted according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491348/what-is-the-size-of-the-cache-provided-by-cacheservice-using-gas). I think the value shouldn't exceed 10MB. Read more on the test conducted [here](https://plus.google.com/+FaustinoRodriguez/posts/61sFPFZ9ZPa).