# Google script custom function errors workaround

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling, google-sheets-custom-function

I am using custom functions in spreadsheets for various operations.
I have used properties service which values is cached. Also, I have send range of values to function instead of calling that function for hundred of times.

I am using function for one column with *100 rows and growing*. I tried to take two column at ones but it exceeds *30 sec* custom function limit.

Nevertheless, I am getting some error messages:

> "Error: Internal error executing the custom function."

because the same custom function *50 times* simultaneously is calculating answers for those *100 rows*.

I am getting this message about *9 times of 50*. It is not strange, because the function is counting a lot of stuff.

The problem would be solved if it would be possible **start the same custom function in different time** or even better if **custom function would run again after error message**. Maybe there is another way too.

I have tried applying Exponential Backoff but I guess it's not possible to do this with custom functions.

I am new to JavaScript and I tried to find workaround for this but it was not successful.

This is the image of spreadsheet that is calling this custom function:

[image: Spreadsheet]

This is the code of my custom function:

```
// Names - range of names e.g. A4:A100
// function is returning number if it meets conditions 
function VSApmokyti(Names, date, place ) {

// if date and place is not arrays
if ( !Array.isArray(date) ) {
  return Names.map (function (d) { 
  return process (d[0], date, place)   
})

}
// if date and place is arrays
else {
return Names.map (function (d) { 
 return date[0].map (function (k, h) {
       return process (d[0], k, place[0][h])   
       })
       })
}
// this function can calculate no matter if date or place is arrays or values
function process(teacher, Vdate, school) {

  if (Vdate=="") {
    return null;
  }
  if (teacher=="") {
    return null;
  }



      // Taking from CACHE
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();

  var teachersL = cache.get("TeachersL");
  teachersL = JSON.parse(teachersL);

  var teachers1 = cache.get("Teachers1");
  teachers1 = JSON.parse(teachers1);  

  var teachers2 = cache.get("Teachers2");
  teachers2 = JSON.parse(teachers2);

  var teachers3 = cache.get("Teachers3");
  teachers3 = JSON.parse(teachers3);  

  var teachers4 = cache.get("Teachers4");
  teachers4 = JSON.parse(teachers4);

  var dates = cache.get("Dates");
  dates = JSON.parse(dates);  

  var Schools = cache.get("Schools");
  Schools = JSON.parse(Schools);

  var number = cache.get("NumberScholars");
  number = JSON.parse(number);   



    if (!number) {

        // WRITING to CACHE
      var TeachersL = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('TeachersL');
      cache.put('TeachersL', TeachersL);
      teachersL = JSON.parse(TeachersL);


      var Teachers1 = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Teachers1');
      cache.put('Teachers1', Teachers1);
      teachers1 = JSON.parse(Teachers1);


      var Teachers2 = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Teachers2');
      cache.put('Teachers2', Teachers2); 
      teachers2 = JSON.parse(Teachers2);


      var Teachers3 = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Teachers3');
      cache.put('Teachers3', Teachers3); 
      teachers3 = JSON.parse(Teachers3);


      var Teachers4 = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Teachers4');
      cache.put('Teachers4', Teachers4); 
      teachers4 = JSON.parse(Teachers4);


      var Dates = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Dates');
      cache.put('Dates', Dates); 
      dates = JSON.parse(Dates);


      var Schools = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Schools');
      cache.put('Schools', Schools); 
      Schools = JSON.parse(Schools);


      var NumberScholars = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('NumberScholars');
      cache.put('NumberScholars', NumberScholars); 
      number = JSON.parse(NumberScholars);

    }


  // converting date from spreadsheet cell to be able check if condition
  Vdate = Vdate.toJSON();

        for(var y = 0; y < Schools.length; y++) { 
       if(Vdate==dates[y] && school==Schools[y]) { 
        if ((teacher==teachersL[y]) || (teacher==teachers1[y]) || (teacher==teachers2[y]) || (teacher==teachers3[y]) || (teacher==teachers4[y]))  {

          return number[y];

        }
      }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What does you custom function does? Have you considered to make it return an array of values instead of a single value? Add a [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for your reply. I am sorry that I haven't put my code in the first place. I have updated my question with image of spreadsheet and code. I think it counts that I am returning an array.

Comment: The question code usually is not the real code. By one hand, code comments should be in English, by the other, it should be minimal, complete a and verifiable (see the previous link)

Comment: @Rubén I have translated everything. I don't know how to make the code more minimal and not throw away necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Instead of a custom function that return a single value, make it return an array of values.

## Explanation

Custom functions could return a single value or an array of values. If you will apply the custom function to contiguous cells, instead of applying a formula that returns a value to each cell resulting in multiple calculations you could use a single formula that returns an array of values but bear in mind that custom functions have a 30 secs time execution limit. See [Optimization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization)

If your function exceeds the 30 secs limit, then use a "regular" function that will be called by a custom menu, dialog, sidebar, trigger or from the Google Apps Script Editor. This kind of functions has a 6 minutes execution time limit for regular accounts and 30 minutes for G Suite accounts that signed up to [Early Access Program](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/apps-script-eap).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read all these things about limitations before. If I am returning function with .map, isn't it the same as returning an array?

Yes, I strongly believe that some of these functions exceeds 30 sec limit. I thought it is possible to workaround it.

Maybe the only solution for me is to rewrite function from custom to regular one.

Comment: "If I am returning function with .map, isn't it the same as returning an array?" I don't know. Have you tried feed your VSApmokyti function with Names, date and place as arrays (2D ranges) ?

Comment: VSApmokyti function takes Names only as an array. Date and place also can be arrays but because of large number of rows I made it possible to read also just values, because it is the same for whole column (Names). I can't imagine how 2D ranges in this case would look like. I think that the best solution is to write regular function and I have to give up optimize it more as a custom function. I guess it's possible to convert this custom function to regular one. What do you think?

Comment: Unless that you are playing with the custom function / Google Sheets limits "just for fun", I think that the best is to write a "regular" function as this will give you more options like implementing batch processing to overcome the 6 / 30 mins time execution limit.

Comment: Oh, I am not doing it just for fun. Lately, it's a pain for me to finish whole project. As I am reading in the book called "Going GAS", batching is described as "Some scripts can be split so that they work on separate sections of the data being processed. Applying the preceding technique, you can use the Properties service of a common library to exchange progress information between scripts so one can pick up where the other left off." How are you suggesting to do it for this function?

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution can work for huge amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle errors in Apps-script. One way that is not too difficult is to use try and catch. For example the code below will write a log to a sheet of any errors that occur while a function is running. Also try and catch is none blocking so function will not stop even if there are errors. Here is an example that will log errors into a Google sheet.

```
function somefunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  try {
    myFunctionThatMightHaveErrors()
  } 

  catch(e){
    var now = new Data();
    var error = JSON.stringify(e);
    logSheet.appendRow([now, error]);
  }

}
```

FYI: Apps-script will run any function for up to 6 minutes, unless your domain is has a Gsuite buisness account and app maker. But there are ways around the time limit if needed.

Comment: I have tried this. I was applying Exponential Backoff (checking errors and if there is error try again for 5 times in a row). I am dealing with custom functions. They have some more limits: 1) running time 30 sec; 2) can't log to spreadsheet; 
By the way, I have updated question with image of spreadsheet and custom function code.

Comment: Do you know there are some limitations to the cache service? It think that the data that can be stored is not much, about 10mb or so. There is mention of it here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24491348/5086349 . That is why I mention using try and catch, because then you see if the cache is sending back any errors.

Comment: I have read that cache service have almost none limits. I guess 100KB per key is more than enough. To compare with properties service key that can have only 9KB of data. If I am importing to cache from properties service I can't reach more than 9 KB per key (I am overwriting cache as you can see in my code). By the way, it takes about 30 sec and than error happens to some cells with custom function.