# Prevent custom functions from executing in Google Spreadsheets Google Apps Script

Tags: caching, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

When writing custom functions to be used in spreadsheet cells, the default behavior for a sheet is to recalculate on edits, i.e. adding column or rows will cause a custom function to update.

This is a problem if the custom function calls a paid API and uses credits, the user will consuming API credits automatically.

I couldn't figure out a way to prevent this, so I decided to use the [UserCache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service#getUserCache()) to cache the results for an arbitrary 25 minutes, and serve it back to the user should they happen to repeat the same function call. It's definitely not bulletproof but it's better than nothing I suppose. Apparently the [cache can hold 10mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491348/what-is-the-size-of-the-cache-provided-by-cacheservice-using-gas), but is this the right approach? Could I be doing something smarter?

```
  var _ROOT = {

  cache : CacheService.getUserCache(),
  cacheDefaultTime: 1500,

  // Step 1 -- Construct a unique name for function call storage using the 
  // function name and arguments passed to the function
  // example: function getPaidApi(1,2,3) becomes "getPaidApi123"

  stringifyFunctionArguments : function(functionName,argumentsPassed) {
    var argstring = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < argumentsPassed.length; i++) {
      argstring += argumentsPassed[i]
    }

    return functionName+argstring

  },

  //Step 2 -- when a user calls a function that uses a paid api, we want to 
  //cache the results for 25 minutes

  addToCache : function (encoded, returnedValues) { 

    var values = {
      returnValues : returnedValues
    }
    Logger.log(encoded)
    this.cache.put(encoded, JSON.stringify(values), this.cacheDefaultTime)

  }

  //Step 3 -- if the user repeats the exact same function call with the same 
  //arguments, we give them the cached result
  //this way, we don't consume API credits as easily. 

  checkCache : function(encoded) {

    var cached = this.cache.get(encoded);

    try {
      cached = JSON.parse(cached)
      return cached.returnValues
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets already caches the values of custom functions, and will only run them again when either a) the inputs to the function have changed or b) the spreadsheet is being opened after being closed for a long time. I'm not able to replicate the recalculation you mentioned when adding and removing columns. Here's a simple example function I used to test that:

```
function rng() {
  return Math.random();
}
```

Your approach of using an additional cache for expensive queries looks fine in general. I'd recommend using the `DocumentCache` instead of the `UserCache`, since all users of the document can and should see the same cell values.

I'd also recommend a more robust encoding of function signatures, since your current implementation is able to distinguish between the arguments `[1, 2]` and `[12]`. You could stringify the inputs and then base64 encode it for compactness:

```
function encode(functionName, argumentsPassed) {
  var data = [functionName].concat(argumentsPassed);
  var json = JSON.stringify(data);
  return Utilities.base64Encode(json);
}
```

Comment: Here's a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t677lw2TeGQ) of the custom function updating when new columns or rows are added. If the function takes in a cell reference as an argument and that cell gets moved (added columns or rows), the custom function updates. Also, if the cell containing the custom function has rows/cols added to it, it updates as well. Ideally, I would block that custom function from updating.

Comment: YouTube won't load the video, saying it is unavailable. Can you check the ACLs?

Comment: Should be OK, just changed it again to unlisted.. Appreciate you taking the time here.