# Is there a limit for caching in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to know - is there a limit on the size of the data? That is, can such a situation occur that the data that I want to cache will not fit into the cache?

Here is a quote from their site:

> The maximum length of a **key** is 250 characters. The maximum amount of data can be stored per **key** is 100KB. The specified expiration time is only a suggestion; cached data may be removed before this time if a lot of data is cached.
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache

I want to know - Is there a limit on the number of **keys**? Or any other limits?

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955915

Answer (score 2):

The maximum length of a key is 250 characters. The maximum amount of data that can be stored per key is 100KB. The value will expire from the cache after 600 seconds (10 minutes

Here is the link to the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putkey,-value

Comment: the docs you've posted talk about properties, not cache. These are two different things

Comment: Thanks for informing me of the mistake.  Sorry about that.  I've changed the answer.