# Form: prevent caching of cell value when looked up via form script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've got a Google form that I've augmented with an apps script that is triggered with the form "on open" event. The script (see below) updates the form description with a value from the source sheet and it works as expected.

The problem arises when the form is submitted and then a new "question" is generated. Because the form updates the sheet, I'd expect the new question to show an updated value in the description. But it shows the previous (outdated) value.

I can force the value to be updated by "running" the script in the script editor.

Is there a work around to prevent the value being cached by the form?

Script:

```
function DisplayBalanceInDescription() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId()).getSheetByName('sheet 1');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var balance = data[0][6]; // first row, 7th column
  form.setDescription("Current account balance is $" + balance);
}
```

Some extra details:

- The value is cached even when the form is viewed in a different browser for the first time, so the browser is not caching the value
- the target sheet for the form is copied to a different sheet via a query function
- the cell that holds the "balance" is a calculation based on the "copied" sheet (above)
- opening/viewing the sheet does not seem to be required as simply running the script results in the value being updated (sheet not open when run)
- I've tried adding a `cell.setFormula("=QUERY('foo bar'))` to my script function, thinking I needed to trigger the query but this had no effect on caching, despite running without any syntax errors
- (edit based on comments) manually editing the spreadsheet and then exiting (so it saves) also results in the form caching the old value, so it appears that the form app is performing its own caching and not the sheets app - I think the call to read the sheet data (`.getValues()` or thereabouts) is where the caching is occurring...

Comment: Can't you use a Flush() call? This will apply all the changes to the sheet and I think it works by updating the cache.

Comment: I tried adding it to the function above but I was not surprised it didn't work, as the docs say "Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes". My script does not make any changes to the SS, as the vanilla form does that after the user has hit submit. I'm not programmatically submitting my form but I suppose I could try it.

Comment: Manually changing the spreadsheet and exiting (so it saves) also results in the form caching the old value, so it appears that the form app is performing its own caching and not the sheets app.

Comment: Seems you have to cross reference your cache version with the version in script properties. A quick search into caching and script properties handed me this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398885/how-to-flush-the-cache

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the cache service - I've read through that Q but I can't see how I can apply it in my case. I'm not explicitly using the cache service so checking cache keys, etc., is not possible. I now think Sheets is caching the value not the Form, because if I manually edit the form then click into another cell, the value in my form gets updated. So the `Flush()` suggestion is on the right track I think... trying a few more things.

Comment: Make sure you put the Flush() at the end of your script.